# Execute two restful actions in one page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have two models, `File` and `Download`. In the same page load, I want to read a `File` (serve it to the user) and create a `Download`.

I could either do:

1. `GET /file/:id`
2. `PUT /file/:id/download`
3. 2 redirected to 1

Is there a correct way of handling such a situation?

Comment: 'create a Download'--you mean load a file in a response, which is downloaded? Also, when you say you want 2 responses--one response is the File being shown and the screen, and one is a download? A bit confusing.

Comment: I keep logs of all the downloads, so create a download means create a download log record. I don't want two responses, but I want to act upon two resources - read a file, and create a download record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need is just an `after_filter` on your file controller. Something along the lines of:

```
  after_filter :log_download, :only => :show

  protected
  def log_download
    # code to log a download after the show action
  end
```

This is a lot simpler than trying to chain together request for the same effect.

Comment: I wasn't looking for implementation details, I was just wondering which one is better according to the REST design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have your file download link point to a :download action, where you can log the download then render your file:

```
def download
  DownloadLog.create(...)
  render :file => ......
end
```